# Problema con el gritView en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy migrando el codigo de windows forms a WPF y tuve un problema con mi dataGridView ya que no puedo usar el .dataSource entonces que podria usar?? ya que dataGrid en WPF no lo admite

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = comando;
    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(tabla);
    dgvUsuarios.""= tabla;
    conexionDB.Close();
```

Comment: Estás usando algun patrón como mvvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar algo como lo siguiente, a reserva que estes ocupando un biding del lado del xaml

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = comando;
DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(tabla);
  
dgvUsuarios.ItemsSource = tabla.DefaultView;
dgvUsuarios.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvUsuarios.CanUserAddRows = false;
conexionDB.Close();
```

Comment: gracias me salvaste la vida